# Probability signal to noise ratio proof

Tags: probability, inequality

If $X$ has mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, the
ratio $r=\dfrac{|\mu|}{\sigma}$ is called the measurement signal-to-noise
ratio of $X$.

If we define $\left|\dfrac{X-\mu}{\mu}\right| = D$ as the relative deviation of $ X$
from its signal (or mean) $\mu$, show that, for $\alpha > 0$

$$\mathbb{P}(D \leq \alpha) \geq 1-\frac{1}{r^2 \alpha^2}$$

I know that this has to do with the Chebyshev inequality, but I just can't figure out how to use it to prove this, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $P(D>\alpha)\le ED^2/\alpha^2$, so $P(D\le\alpha)\ge1- ED^2/\alpha^2$.  Note also that $ED^2=\mathrm{Var}(X)/\mu^2$, so $ED^2/\alpha^2 = 1/(r^2\alpha^2)$.

Comment: Yes, of course.